# Just completed a domain upgrade 2008 - 2012 R2. IP Address show Unknown for domain controllers on Name Servers tab in DNS in Reverse Lookup Zones

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2

Is there anyway to automate updating all of the Reverse Lookup Zones without having to go through each one and click Edit - Resolve?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be any way to automate updating all of the Reverse Lookup Zones.

I looked into using command line (dnscmd.exe) and powershell (Add-DnsServerResourceRecord) but both commands only give the option to enter the DNS alias.  I couldn't find an option to specify the IP address.